# Ammeter and Voltmeter for the circuit TikZ library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

How can I make the Voltmeter and Ammeter symbols look like in the follwing picture using the `circuits.ee.IEC` library?

[image: Ammeter and Voltmeter]

I just managed to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}


\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ammeter}
\tikzset{set ammeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
   \draw (0,0) to[ammeter] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: empty ammeter]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the `generic circle IEC` shape. So you would put `\node (name) [generic circle IEC, draw] at (location) {A}` for the Ammeter. Just replace the `A` with a `V` for the voltmeter. If this is not exactly what you mean or you need additional information on how to apply it to your specific case, you should provide a minimal working example showing the diagram you have so far without the meters.

**Edit:** In response to your edit, you can simply use the `info` option to get a label and use `center` as the angle to position this label in the center of the shape. Your example then becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = ammeter}
\tikzset{set ammeter graphic ={draw,generic circle IEC, minimum size=5mm,info=center:A}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw (0,0) to[ammeter] (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Annotated symbol]

Comment: @student: see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-2)(9,6.5)
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,6)(3.1,6)(5.9,6)(9,6)(9,0)(8.2,0)(5.5,0)
  \circledipole[
    labeloffset = 0
  ](P0)(P1){$A$}
  \battery(P1)(P3){}
  \battery(P2)(P4){}
  \wire(P4)(P5)
  \wire(P5)(P6)
  \lamp(P6)(P7){}
  \circledipole[
    labeloffset = 0,
    parallel,
    parallelsep = 0.2,
    parallelarm = 1.5,
    parallelnode
  ](P6)(P7){$U$}
  \lamp(P7)(P0){}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that in the coordinates for the nodes, I've choosen `3.1` and `5.9` instead of `3` and `6`. These choices avoid an overlap in the drawing of the two batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see whether this helps you

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (4,4) to [battery] (0,4) -- (0,0) to [lamp] (4,0)--(4,4) -- (1,0);
\draw (1,-2)--(3,-2)--(3,0);
\draw (0,2)[black,fill=white]circle [radius=12pt];

\node at (0,2) {A};
\draw (2,-2)[black,fill=white]circle [radius=12pt];
\node at (2,-2) {V};
\end{circuitikz}
```

I've added a circle with the labeling at the required position, instead of using the built-in ammeter and voltmeter symbol