# Rotate voltmeter CircuiTikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using Latex and CircuiTikz to draw circuits but I can't rotate de voltmeter without making a disaster. Any idea? Here is an example.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[ammeter] (3,0)
      to (4,0)
      to[lamp] (4,-2)
      to (0,-2)
      to[sV] (0,0);
\draw (3,0) to[voltmeter] (3,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I "compile" code to show the example circuit?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again. It is better to turn your code snippet into a (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}` and including the necessary packages. This will help who wants to answer you. `:)`

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56037/13482) answer might be helpful. If you need the arrow too, uncomment all the lines.

Answer (score 12):

There is a simpler scheme to achieve the goal.  A proposed approach that defines a `mymeter` command taking 2 arguments `\#1=name`, `\#2=angle` of rotation. Basically it redefines the `voltmeter` by drawing a mymeter that has the rotation ability.

```
\newcommand{\mymeter}[2] 
{  % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[thick] (#1)node(){$\mathbf V$} circle (11pt);
\draw[rotate=45,-latex] (#1)  +(-17pt,0) --+(17pt,0);
\end{scope}
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\mymeter}[2] 
{  % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[thick] (#1)node(){$\mathbf V$} circle (11pt);
\draw[rotate=45,-latex] (#1)  +(-17pt,0) --+(17pt,0);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

OP's circuit:

\medskip

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[ammeter] (3,0)
      to (4,0)
      to[lamp] (4,-2)
      to (0,-2)
      to[sV] (0,0);
\draw (3,0) to[voltmeter] (3,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\medskip

Result of proposed approach:

\medskip

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[ammeter] (3,0)
      to (4,0)
      to[lamp] (4,-2)
      to (0,-2)
      to[sV] (0,0);
\draw (3,0) to[voltmeter,color=white,name=M](3,-2);
\mymeter{M}{0}  % try 90, 0, -90
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

I see that in the last version of `circuitikz`, the definitions for ammeter and voltmeter have been changed, so if your version is 0.3.0 or newer, use the following code. If you don't need the diagonal arrow, comment the last two `\pgfusepath{draw}`. However I notice that now the circles don't touch the wires (I wonder why). If you want to correct this behaviour, replace the lines

```
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{.9\pgf@circ@res@up}
<...>
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
```

with

```
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@circ@res@up}
<...>
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1.06\pgf@circ@res@other}{1.06\pgf@circ@res@up}}
```

but then you have to do the same in the ammeter definition.
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@circ@myvoltmeter@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{myvoltmeter}{#1}}
\tikzset{myvoltmeter/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to
                               path=\pgf@circ@myvoltmeter@path}}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/voltmeter/height}}{myvoltmeter}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/voltmeter/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/voltmeter/width}}{
    \def\pgf@circ@temp{right}
    \ifx\tikz@res@label@pos\pgf@circ@temp
        \pgf@circ@res@step=-1.2\pgf@circ@res@up
    \else
        \def\pgf@circ@temp{below}
        \ifx\tikz@res@label@pos\pgf@circ@temp
            \pgf@circ@res@step=-1.2\pgf@circ@res@up
        \else
            \pgf@circ@res@step=1.2\pgf@circ@res@up
        \fi
    \fi

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}       
    \pgfpointorigin \pgf@circ@res@other =  \pgf@x  \advance \pgf@circ@res@other by -\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

        \pgfscope
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{.9\pgf@circ@res@up} % change this if you want to touch the wires
            \pgfusepath{draw}       
        \endpgfscope    

    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgftransformrotate{90}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}} % change this if you want to touch the wires
    \pgfusepath{draw} % comment this if you don't need the diagonal arrow
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}


    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfusepath{draw} % comment this if you don't need the diagonal arrow

    \pgfnode{circle}{center}{\textbf{V}}{}{}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[ammeter] (3,0)
      to (4,0)
      to[lamp] (4,-2)
      to (0,-2)
      to[sV] (0,0);
\draw (3,0) to[myvoltmeter] (3,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW. Thats a lot of code just to rotate the voltmeter, but thanks it works.

Comment: @Agustin it's not completely my own work! I simply defined a new component by copying the code for the original voltmeter from `pgfcircbipoles.tex`, and adding a row of code to rotate the label (and reusing an old answer of mine).

Answer (score 4):

With Version 0.9.5 (Oct 12, 2019), This is possible with `rmeter` (Round meter)

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0) to[ammeter] (3,0)
    to (6,0)
    to[lamp] (6,-2)
    to (0,-2)
    to[sV] (0,0);
    \draw (3,0) to[voltmeter] (3,-2);
    \draw
    (4,0) to[rmeter, n=rm1] (4,-2)
    (rm1.center) node [anchor=center] () {V}
    ;
    \draw
    (5,0) to[rmeterwa, n=rm2] (5,-2)
    (rm2.center) node [anchor=center] () {A}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the solution proposed by the manual. Note that you can set the label directly with `to [rmeterwa, t=V]` instead of adding it afterwards.