# Drawing a circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, circuitikz

> How can I create the following drawing?

I want to add the following diagram to my report:

[image: wanted]

I hear it can be done in LaTeX so I read some of https://es.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/09/02/tikz-series-pt4.html and try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw
    (0,0) to[battery] (0,6.5)
    to[ammeter] (5.5,6.5) to[resistor] (5.5,0) 

  (2.5,0) to[voltmeter] (2.5,6.5)
;
\end{circuittikz}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I'm too bad, I market the coordinates in the corners.

Comment: `node[above left]{$(0; 6{,}5)$}`? What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don;t think the OP *wants* to mark the corners, I think he's marked what the coordinates are supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, I just marked the coordinates to help with diagram nodes. I don't know how to draw this large resistor or the box in batery

Comment: Can you please post an example that actually compiles?  You need to check the basic syntax of `\draw`...  Each draw statement is supposed to end with a `;` mark.

Comment: @Thruston there is only one `\draw` statement, so there's only one `;`; nothing wrong with that. The reason it doesn't compile is simply the typo in `\end{circuittikz}` (should be `\end{circuitikz}`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % used for the \overset macro
\usepackage{pst-circ} % used for the electrical components

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.25,0)(6.33,7) % boundry found manually
  \psline[arrowscale = 1.5, arrowinset = 0]{->}(0,0)(3.5,0)(3.5,3.25)(5,3.25)
  \psline(0,5)(0,6.5)(2.5,6.5)
  \circledipole[labeloffset = 0](2.5,6.5)(5.5,6.5){A}
  \psline(0,0)(0,1)
  \vdc(0,3)(0,1){$\overset{+}{-}$}
  \rput(-1,2){$\mathcal{E}$}
  \resistor[dipolestyle = zigzag](0,3)(0,5){$r$}
  \psframe[linestyle = dashed](-1.25,1.5)(1.0,4.9)
  \circledipole[labeloffset = 0](2.5,0)(2.5,6.5){V}
  \resistor[dipolestyle = zigzag](5.5,6.5)(5.5,0){$R$}
  \psline(5.3,0)(5.7,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: beautiful, but it doen't compile in my latex, no spaces between coordinates?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez It compiles fine for me. You are using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`, right? Also, what do you mean by "no spaces between coordinates"?

Comment: I'm using Texstudio, I mean for example : ´\psline (5.3,0)--(5.7,0)´

Comment: That you are using TeXstudio has nothing to do with it; it's just your editor. Again: I don't understand what you mean; `\psline(5.3,0)(5.7,0)` is nothing more than a small line segment so what does "no spaces between coordinates" mean?

Comment: ah, okey, It compiles fine in Overleaf.com, so I need to change to ps2pdf because i'm using latexpdf

Comment: Beautiful!  But shouldn't the `\mathcal{E}` be a `\(var)epsilon`?

Comment: @PålGD Maybe it looks more like a `\varepsilon` but I've seen `\mathcal{E}` in textbooks; I've never seen `\varepsilon`.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this (correcting the typo mentioned in the comments)?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0)
    to[battery] (0,6.5)
    to[ammeter] (5.5,6.5) to[resistor] (5.5,0) (2.5,0) to[voltmeter] (2.5,6.5)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: basic circuit]

Extending it a bit and adding a few labels:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[font=\sffamily]
  \draw
  (0,0) to [battery, l=$\varepsilon$, n=batt] (0,3.25) to [R=r] (0,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5) to [ammeter] (5.5,6.5) to [R=R] (5.5,0) node [rground] {}
    (0,0) -- (2.5,0) to [voltmeter] (2.5,6.5)
    [-{Triangle[]}] (2.5,0) -- (3.5,0) |- (5,3.25)
    ;
  \node [label=0:$+$] at ([xshift=12.5pt]batt.east) {};
  \node [label=0:$-$] at ([xshift=12.5pt]batt.west) {};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: extended circuit]

## EDIT

I forgot to add the final version. You can use the `fit` library to create the dashed container around the battery and the resistor if you give them names.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fit}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[font=\sffamily]
  \draw
  (0,0) to [battery, l=$\varepsilon$, n=batt] (0,3.25) to [R=r,n=res] (0,6.5) -- (2.5,6.5) to [ammeter] (5.5,6.5) to [R=R] (5.5,0) node [rground] {}
    (0,0) -- (2.5,0) to [voltmeter] (2.5,6.5)
    [-{Triangle[]}] (2.5,0) -- (3.5,0) |- (5,3.25)
    ;
  \node [label=0:$+$] at ([xshift=10pt]batt.east) {};
  \node [label=0:$-$] at ([xshift=10pt]batt.west) {};
  \node [dashed, draw, inner xsep=15pt, fit=(batt) (res)] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: final circuit]

Comment: The `V-meter`` should be rotated for 90 degrees.

Comment: @Zarko I'm sure you are right. I couldn't figure out how to do that, though. These don't seem to behave like regular nodes.... (This is the first time I've used `circuitikz` and I did not find the documentation overly helpful. Doubtless my fault.)

Comment: Somewhere in SE I sow the solution for this, but now I can't remember a question and answer for it. If I will find it or figured out how to do this, I will inform you about it.

Comment: Here is solution for rotating V-meter: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105864/rotate-voltmeter-circuitikz

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. Having looked at the answers, I think I'll have to come back to this later. I had assumed I was missing something simple, but I guess not. On the other hand, I'm not sure that it should be rotated at all. Isn't non-rotation the intended behaviour? (By default, TikZ would not rotate the text, I don't think. So presumably the package does something specifically to ensure that it *is* rotated?) I haven't drawn one of these since high school, mind.