# Draw a wattmeter

Tags: graphics, circuitikz

How can I draw a wattmeter using LaTeX and circuitikz? I want to use the one with a big circle and W inside, and 4 circles (up, down, left right) which contain respectively 2 + and 2 -, [image: like the one in this pic]
Thank you everyone

Comment: Have you made any attempt so far? If so please show what code you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! :) It would be useful if you included at least the code for the rest of the circuit, so we don't have to type it from scratch.

Comment: One can make one easily enough (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274896/no-drawing-of-ohmmeter-or-multimeter-using-circuitikz/275079#275079 for example) but why would you want 4 leads on a wattmeter?   Three leads (in, out and ground) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

this wattmeter symbol looks very strange to me, never seen before. Nevertheless, you can use an empty source and some tikz-node to achieve it, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\esourcetowattmeter}[1]{
    \draw (#1)node{W};
    \draw (#1.north) node[circle,draw,anchor=south,inner sep=0,fill=white,minimum width=2.5mm]{\tiny +};
    \draw (#1.south) node[circle,draw,anchor=north,inner sep=0,fill=white,minimum width=2.5mm]{\tiny +};
    \draw (#1.east) node[circle,draw,anchor=west,inner sep=0,fill=white,minimum width=2.5mm]{\tiny -};
    \draw (#1.west) node[circle,draw,anchor=east,inner sep=0,fill=white,minimum width=2.5mm]{\tiny -};
}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R]++(2,0) coordinate(left) to [esource,n=wattmeter]++(2,0) to [L]++(2,0);

\draw (left)to [short,*-]++(0,1)-|(wattmeter.north);
\draw (wattmeter.south) to [R]++(0,-2);

\esourcetowattmeter{wattmeter}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

Best regards,
Stefan