# A problem with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, circuitikz

I have a simple circuit and a problem. The coding of the circuit can be seen here:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]

%CIRCUIT
\draw(0,0)
to[vsourcesin] (2,0)
to[transformer](2,2)
to[lamp](0,2)
to[closing switch,->](0,0)
;



%ADDING VOLTMETER
\draw
(.25,2)to[short,*-](.25,4)
       to[voltmeter,l=$U$](1.75,4)
       to[short,-*](1.75,2)

;


%NODES
\draw(1,1.6)node{lamp};
\draw(1,3.6)node{voltmeter};
\end{circuitikz}

\caption{\textit{{\small Peter's circuit}}}
\end{figure}
```

Why doesn't circuitikz show the transformer? In my document there is no transformer when I build the code.

Comment: `transformer` is a node style, i.e. you have to use it like `node[transformer] {}`.  Unfortunately, I don't know where you want it to be placed, thus I cannot straighforwardly answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing electrical schemes with `circuitikz` is not so flexible as ones desired, so the some elements as voltmeters, transformers etc need special effort to be rotated in desired orientation (see [rotate voltmeter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105864/rotate-voltmeter-circuitikz), etc), so the scheme -- based on guessing about real circuit -- can be drawn as:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]
%CIRCUIT
\draw (0,0) node[transformer] (T) {};
\coordinate[left=2cm] (a) at (T.A1);
\draw (a) to [closing switch] (T.A1)
      (a) to [vsourcesin]    (a |- T.A2)
          to [lamp] (T.A2);

%ADDING VOLTMETER
\draw (T.B1) to[voltmeter,l=$U$,*-] ++ (1,0) coordinate (b)
             to (b |- T.B2) 
             to [short,-*] (T.B2);
\end{circuitikz}    
%\caption{Peter's circuit}
%\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]