# Arc arrow to indicate a loop of electric flow

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I would like to draw an electric circuit diagram that looks like this:

[image: Circuit diagram to draw]

I am suffering from those circular flows $i_1(t),i_2(t)$ (I drew them in red to point out; they actually don't need to be colored).

I have so far coded:

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}
        \ctikzset{inductor=american}
        \draw(0,0)to[open,v^>=$v_i(t)$,o-o](0,2);
        \draw(0,2)to[short,o-*,R=$R_1$](2,2)to[short,*-*,L=$L$](2,0);
        \draw(2,2)to[short,*-*,R=$R_2$](4,2)to[C,*-,l_=$C$,v^<=$v_o(t)$](4,0);
        \draw(0,0)to[short,-*](2,0)to[short,*-](4,0);
        % FIXME the following line and so far
        \draw(1,1.5)arc[short,start angle=90,end angle=-90,I=$i_1(t)$,radius=0.5];
\end{circuitikz}
```

, which outputs:

[image: What I have drawn]

Comment: possible duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548319/197451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3.1314592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{inductor=american}
\draw   (0,0)   to [open,v^>=$v_i(t)$]  ++ (0,2) 
                to [R=$R_1$,o-*]        ++ (2,0) coordinate (L)
                to [R=$R_2$,*-*]        ++ (3,0)
                to [C,a=$C$,v^<=$v_o(t)$] ++ (0,-2)
                to [short, *-o] (0,0)
        (L)     to [L=$L$,-*]           ++ (0,-2);
%
% now is FIXED  :-)
\draw[->]   (0.8,1.5) arc(110:-110:5mm) node[midway, left, font=\footnotesize] {$i_1(t)$};
\draw[->]   (3.3,1.5) arc(110:-110:5mm) node[midway, left, font=\footnotesize] {$i_2(t)$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or (to my opinion better):

[image]

where MWE is

```
\documentclass[border=3.1314592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{inductor=american,
          bipoles/capacitor/height=0.4,
          bipoles/capacitor/width=0.1
          }
\draw   (0,0)   to [open,v^>=$v_i(t)$]  ++ (0,2) 
                to [R=$R_1$,o-*]        ++ (2,0) coordinate (L)
                to [R=$R_2$,*- ]        ++ (3,0)
                to [C,a=$C$,v^<=$v_o(t)$] ++ (0,-2)
                to [short,  -o] (0,0)
        (L)     to [L=$L$,-*]           ++ (0,-2);
%
% now is FIXED  :-)
\draw[->]   (0.8,1.5) arc(110:-110:5mm) node[midway, left, font=\footnotesize] {$i_1(t)$};
\draw[->]   (3.7,0.5) arc(290:  70:5mm) node[midway, right,font=\footnotesize] {$i_2(t)$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are Great 

Comment: @Sebastiano, really? You are so kind and also magician: how you put this nice smiles in comment?

Comment: @Zarko which OS are you using?  In Linux it's quite easy...

Comment: @Sebastiano, I'm on  M$ .W10. But I have a plan go to W11 when I will buy a new PC (now I'm on 15 year old machine, but it still works however it is very slow ). I'm to old to learn new OS :-(

Comment: One can always open    https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html  and do a copy&paste:  ;-)

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much!

Comment: I use the smartphone for the emoji  or the solution of rmano 

Comment: @Sebastiano, so far i use my (smart)phone only for talking and sms ...  (i found how to this here in comment)

Comment: @Sebastiano, Zarko: for windows I suggest this: https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose  --- very nice and powerful

Comment: @Rmano Great and beautiful solution