# How to move current arrow further away from components and color it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How can I shift the arrow more to the far way from the components and color both arrows and labels differently as in the image?

[image]

> (Placing the label below the arrow probably makes it look a bit better
> but I prefer to put it on top.)

I have been trying to apply this from manual but couldn't make it work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/voltage/distance from node/.initial=0.4};
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/voltage/distance from node/.initial=0.7};

\ctikzset{!i/.style={ no i symbols}};

\newcommand{\iarronly}[1]{% name
\node [currarrow, color=red, anchor=center,
rotate=\ctikzgetdirection{#1-Iarrow}] at (#1-Ipos) {};
}

\draw (0,0) node[ocirc,scale=2]{} to [C,
i>^=$I_C$,
v^=$V_C$
] ++(3,0)  to
[cute inductor,
v^=$V_L$, 
i^>= $I_L$,
voltage/american label distance=0.8pt] ++(1.5,0) to 
[short, name=  LL,!i] ++(1,0)node[ocirc,scale=2] {};


% \iarronly{LL};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548319/197451

Comment: Can't confirm, but the `no i symbol` needs a current specifier to get the direction and above/below position. Try ` to [short, name=  LL, i, !i] ++(1,0)` (or `i<` or whatever).

Comment: @jsbibra Nice drawig but I want to place the arrow on the circuit instead and also be able to move the arrow along to some desired position. The built-in arrow always places too close to the component.

Comment: @Rmano probably something else as those two don't work. I also tried to change like `i>` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @Rmano would it be able to change the color for the bult-in current arrow without changing the component color?  `[L, i=$I_{L}$, color=red,  bipole current append style={color=red}]` would make the inductor red as well (in case where you don't want to add `short` ).

Comment: @internet I don't think --- the problem is that color is a path-wide property in Ti*k*Z, you can't change it locally. For this the "advanced" thing exists --- to be able to use another path (there is something in the FAQ in the manual). RL calling now, I'll try to check why your code is not working later.

Comment: Hi, if in your code I use `to [short, name=LL, i, !i] ++(1,0)` and then `\iarrow{LL}`  I have the red arrow correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(without use of at use `current arrow scale=...`

**Edit:**
You can scale currents arrows by option `current arrow scale=<denominator of size>`. Now added to `\ctikzset`, but can be inserted locally too.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.075,
          current arrow scale=8 
          }
\draw   (0,0)   node[ocirc] {}
                to [short, i=$I_{C}$, color=red,
                    bipole current append style={color=red}]   ++ (1,0)
                to [C, v^=$V_C$] ++ (2,0)
                to [cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++ (2,0)
                to [short, i=$I_{L}$, color=blue,
                    bipole current append style={color=blue}]   ++ (1,0)
                node[ocirc] {};
    \end{circuitikz}


\end{document}
```

at use `current arrow scale=8`

[image]

Comment: Exactly, very nice. I was looking for how to draw arrow tip only as an alternative.

Comment: How would you scale the arrow head? Just prepare if I need it in the future.

Comment: @internet, so far, as I know, this is not possible without use of node (as you try) .  What you like (me too) seems to be new feature request. We should wait to respond of package author ...

Comment: @internet, for scaling of current arrows exist option `current arrow scale=<denominator>`. See edited answer.

Comment: Trust @Zarko to know `circuitikz` way better than me! 

Comment: Thank you. One problem with `[L, i=$I_{L}$, color=red,  bipole current append style={color=red}]` would make the inductor red as well (in case  where you don't want to add `short` ).

Comment: @internet, than add color to inductor: `[cute inductor, v^=$V_L$, color=red]`. See package documentation, section `7 Colors`, page 206.

Comment: I mean this `[cute inductor, v^=$V_L$, i>^= $I_L$,bipole current append style={color=red},color=red]` The first one  `bipole current append style={color=red},color=red]`  would change the label to red  and the second one unfortunately change color of both inductor and the bult-in arrow. I only want to change the color of the arrow and the label and keep the inductor black. Adding `short` for the arrow alone works but it reguires more space sometimes.

Comment: @internet, I can't confirm what you claim in comment. Sorry, now your question is not clear anymore. BTW, this site is not a forum. If you have new problem, please ask new question.

Comment: Your answer works very well. It's just that I wonder if I can do it without using `[short...]` as well. Probably like 90% of the cases adding `[short...]` would be no problem but some cases it consumes more spaces. Let me modify the post to see if there is a way to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll make a new question for this.